# issue looping through each value of a 2D Jagged Array "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I generate a 2D Jagged Array from a text file, the array is Paragraphs > Sentences, this array is formed correctly, and I can specify outside a value such as [0][0] etc and it'll display correctly.

However when I try and do this within the loop I get "Index was outside the bounds of the array" when trying to display "results[0][0]".

Below is the array generation code:

```
string documentPath = @"I:\Project\Test Text.txt";
string content;
string[][] results;

protected void sentenceSplit()
{
    content = Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(documentPath), @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    var paragraphs = content.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
    results = new string[paragraphs.Length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
    {
        results[i] = Regex.Split(paragraphs[i], @"(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s");
    }
}
```

And here is the loop code:

```
protected void Intersection()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int s = 0; s < results.Length; s++)
        {
            TextboxSummary.Text += results[i][s];
        } 
    } 
}
```

I've not done much work with 2D arrays before but feel this should work, when its tested it doesn't output anything to the text box even though it should be starting on [0][0] which certainly holds data, also [1][1] holds data as well if its somehow skipping to that.

Comment: Isn't `results.Length` in your outer loop and `results.Length` in your inner loop referring to the same object?  IIRC, `Length` will return the size of the first dimension only.  I think you want `results[i].Length` in your inner loop.

Comment: Boom there we go, totally missed that, now its pointed out I can't unsee it thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  Sometimes all it takes is a second set of eyes, especially if you've been stuck on the same section of code for some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I put in my comment, your code is grabbing the wrong array length in your inner loop.   Your inner loop should be getting the length of the array that is at the index of the outer loop. like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
{
    // Get the length of the array that is at index i
    for (int s = 0; s < results[i].Length; s++)
    {
        TextboxSummary.Text += results[i][s];
    } 
}
```